# D3v4 Stacked Barchart Tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using `d3.stack()` to create a normalized stacked barchart.
But I'm having trouble accessing the relevant values of the inital dataset for a mousover tooltip.

```
serie.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      ...
      .on("mousemove", function(d){
          let coords = d3.mouse(svg.node());
          tooltip.style("left", coords[0] + "px");
          tooltip.style("top", coords[1] - 70 + "px");
          tooltip.style("display", "inline-block");
          tooltip.html("HOW TO ACCESS DATA HERE?");
        });
```

`d` is the `Array[2]` at this point with the values defining baseline / topline, `d.data` is the complete original data object but is missing the information over which stack of the series I'm currently hovering.
Ideally I want the tooltip to show for a dataset like `{name:"item1", foo:10, bar:20}`

```
value: 10
percentage: 33%
```

when hovering above the `foo` rect.
All the examples I've found are for D3v3 where you can simply use `d.y` to access the relevant value but that doesn't seem to work any more with D3v4.

Comment: The first argument (`d`) in v4 is exactly the same of v3. I suggest you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Then my assumption that it was version related was wrong, nonetheless the question remains: how do I know over which rect of the series I'm hovering? According to this example (http://bl.ocks.org/mstanaland/6100713)  it should just be `d.y` but here is the fiddle where it doesn't work since `d` is the stack array: https://jsfiddle.net/vu624zrg/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the name of the element accessing the parent's data, and using that name to get the value:

```
.on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
    var thisName = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().key;
    var thisValue = d.data[thisName];
    var total = d.data.foo + d.data.bar;
    tooltip.html("Name: " + thisName + "<br>Value: " + thisValue + "<br>Percentage: " + thisValue / total + "%");
});
```

Here is your code with that modification:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 60,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
    },
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .padding(0.1)
    .align(0.1);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);
var stack = d3.stack()
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetExpand);

var colors = ["#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF"];

var data = [{
    name: "item1",
    foo: 10,
    bar: 20
}, {
    name: "item2",
    foo: 50,
    bar: 50
}];

x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.name;
}));

var serie = g.selectAll(".serie")
    .data(stack.keys(["foo", "bar"])(data))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "serie")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colors[i];
    });


var tooltip = d3.select('#tooltip');

var rects = serie.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) {
        return d;
    })
    .enter().append("rect")

rects.attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.data.name);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
    })
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
        var thisName = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().key;
        var thisValue = d.data[thisName];
        var total = d.data.foo + d.data.bar;
        tooltip.html("Name: " + thisName + "<br>Value: " + thisValue + "<br>Percentage: " + thisValue / total + "%");
    });

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, "%"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<div id="tooltip">tooltip</div>
<svg width="500" height="300"></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, `d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().key` was the part I couldn't figure out!

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado how can we move the tooltip above the bars upon hover? This might be a quick fix for someone as knowledgeable as you. Thanks.