# How to change tooltip in D3v4 stacked chart so only the specific value being hovered over shows and not all values stacked in that bar?

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3 and coding generally. I have made a stacked barchart combing various code samples from the web. I have added a tooltip that shows on hover however, it shows the values for all of the 4 values stacked in each bar. I'd like to change it so that it only shows the value for the specific portion of the bar being hovered on - i.e. when you hover for example over the portion of the bar showing employees part-time in Q1 2016 it only shows that one value, not the values for each type of employment for that quarter. I have tried adjusting the code in this line :

html((d.data.month) + "
" +  (d.data.employeesfulltime)+ "
"+ (d.data.employeesparttime)+ "
"+ (d.data.selfemployedfulltime)+ "
"+  (d.data.selfemployedparttime));
                    })

but cannot work out how to  change it so that only the value for one value shows per quarter depending on what is being hovered on without breaking the whole chart.

Any help much appreciated - thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg width="500" height="450"></svg>
<style>
.title {
    font: 15px sans-serif;
}

.legend {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}


.axis {
    fill: none;
    stroke:  #D3D3D3;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}


.axis path, line {
    fill: none;
    stroke:  #D3D3D3;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}


.centerline {

  display: none;
}

.g-num:hover {
    fill: orange;
}


.toolTip {
    position: absolute;
  display: none;
  min-width: 80px;
  height: auto;
    font-family: 'Proxima-Nova', sans-serif;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 12px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}



</style>
<body>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>
var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 10, left: 40};
var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", width)
                                    .attr("height", height);




var data = [

    {month:"Q1 '08", employeesfulltime: 0, employeesparttime: 0, 
selfemployedfulltime:0, selfemployedparttime:0,},
    {month:"Q2 '08", employeesfulltime: 0, employeesparttime: 0, 
selfemployedfulltime:0, selfemployedparttime:0,},
    {month:"Q3 '08", employeesfulltime: -6777, employeesparttime: 51501, 
selfemployedfulltime:16050, selfemployedparttime:-32449,},
    {month:"Q4 '08", employeesfulltime: -96761, employeesparttime:  81769, 
selfemployedfulltime:-1062, selfemployedparttime:-5506},
    {month:"Q1 '09", employeesfulltime: -309785, employeesparttime: 122849, 
selfemployedfulltime:19145, selfemployedparttime:-9577},
    {month:"Q2 '09", employeesfulltime: -551303, employeesparttime:72870, 
selfemployedfulltime:-30054, selfemployedparttime:38568},
    {month:"Q3 '09", employeesfulltime: -670405, employeesparttime:150698   , 
selfemployedfulltime:4329, selfemployedparttime:42839 },
    {month:"Q4 '09", employeesfulltime: -722566, employeesparttime:188715, 
selfemployedfulltime:18484, selfemployedparttime:59652 },
    {month:"Q1 '10", employeesfulltime: -857511, employeesparttime: 180270 , 
selfemployedfulltime:41246, selfemployedparttime:78834},
    {month:"Q2 '10", employeesfulltime:-788732, employeesparttime:286291, 
selfemployedfulltime:29292, selfemployedparttime:85782 },
    {month:"Q3 '10", employeesfulltime: -809966, employeesparttime: 394568, 
selfemployedfulltime:91558, selfemployedparttime:119911 },
    {month:"Q4 '10", employeesfulltime: -767250, employeesparttime:343597, 
selfemployedfulltime:38972, selfemployedparttime:135368},
    {month:"Q1 '11", employeesfulltime: -597501, employeesparttime: 310817, 
selfemployedfulltime:-15309, selfemployedparttime:164306},
    {month:"Q2 '11", employeesfulltime: -577162, employeesparttime: 302685, 
selfemployedfulltime:7145, selfemployedparttime:166872},
    {month:"Q3 '11", employeesfulltime: -720538, employeesparttime:166016, 
selfemployedfulltime:80965, selfemployedparttime:206414 },
    {month:"Q4 '11", employeesfulltime: -783933, employeesparttime: 281013, 
selfemployedfulltime:90085, selfemployedparttime:190036},
    {month:"Q1 '12", employeesfulltime: -782690, employeesparttime:310385, 
selfemployedfulltime:93579, selfemployedparttime:257762},
    {month:"Q2 '12", employeesfulltime: -699356, employeesparttime: 358013, 
selfemployedfulltime:136651, selfemployedparttime:253744},
    {month:"Q3 '12", employeesfulltime: -649809, employeesparttime:383590, 
selfemployedfulltime:117944, selfemployedparttime:280489},
    {month:"Q4 '12", employeesfulltime: -515492, employeesparttime: 362100, 
selfemployedfulltime:148464, selfemployedparttime:273576},
    {month:"Q1 '13", employeesfulltime: -482007, employeesparttime:361642, 
selfemployedfulltime:117686, selfemployedparttime:231430},
    {month:"Q2 '13", employeesfulltime: -423430, employeesparttime: 366980, 
selfemployedfulltime:114520, selfemployedparttime:247586},
    {month:"Q3 '13", employeesfulltime: -320157, employeesparttime:378434, 
selfemployedfulltime:167346, selfemployedparttime:243414 },
    {month:"Q4 '13", employeesfulltime: -243715, employeesparttime: 336727, 
selfemployedfulltime:291825, selfemployedparttime:296264},
    {month:"Q1 '14", employeesfulltime: -185351, employeesparttime:376992, 
selfemployedfulltime:371302, selfemployedparttime:370939},
    {month:"Q2 '14", employeesfulltime: -31827, employeesparttime: 372880, 
selfemployedfulltime:365482, selfemployedparttime:406676},
    {month:"Q3 '14", employeesfulltime: 129625, employeesparttime:406338, 
selfemployedfulltime:360465, selfemployedparttime:337240},
    {month:"Q4 '14", employeesfulltime: 252208, employeesparttime:  440130, 
selfemployedfulltime:307835, selfemployedparttime:371345},
    {month:"Q1 '15", employeesfulltime: 390796, employeesparttime:509528, 
selfemployedfulltime:303717, selfemployedparttime:381675},
    {month:"Q2 '15", employeesfulltime: 431678, employeesparttime: 441827, 
selfemployedfulltime:299409, selfemployedparttime:385673},
    {month:"Q3 '15", employeesfulltime: 481269, employeesparttime:544872, 
selfemployedfulltime:327446, selfemployedparttime:414819},
    {month:"Q4 '15", employeesfulltime: 607865, employeesparttime:  525241, 
selfemployedfulltime:398944, selfemployedparttime:442504},
    {month:"Q1 '16", employeesfulltime: 581538, employeesparttime:565479, 
selfemployedfulltime:436068, selfemployedparttime:432070},
    {month:"Q2 '16", employeesfulltime: 642936, employeesparttime: 586587, 
selfemployedfulltime:498349, selfemployedparttime:449921},
    {month:"Q3 '16", employeesfulltime: 672094, employeesparttime:609383, 
selfemployedfulltime:499016, selfemployedparttime:451853 },
    {month:"Q4 '16", employeesfulltime:695133   , employeesparttime:    
598618, selfemployedfulltime:516310, selfemployedparttime:38568, 
other:446401},
    {month:"Q1 '17", employeesfulltime: 891547, employeesparttime:537917, 
selfemployedfulltime:517225, selfemployedparttime:432854}

];

var series = d3.stack()
    .keys(["employeesfulltime", "employeesparttime", "selfemployedfulltime", 
"selfemployedparttime"])
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetDiverging)
    (data);

var labels =    ["Employed full-time", "Employed part-time", "Self-employed 
full-time", "Self-employed part-time"];

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }))
    .rangeRound([margin.left, width - margin.right])
        .padding(0.1)

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([d3.min(series, stackMin), d3.max(series, stackMax)])
    .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

var center = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([0, width]);

var centerLine = d3.axisTop(center).ticks(0);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", ]);

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

svg.append("g")
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(series)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })

  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "g-num")
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.month); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
        .on("mousemove", function(d){
                    tooltip
                      .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px")
                      .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
                      .style("display", "inline-block")
                      .html((d.data.month) + "<br>" +  
(d.data.employeesfulltime)+ "<br>"+ (d.data.employeesparttime)+ "<br>"+ 
(d.data.selfemployedfulltime)+ "<br>"+  (d.data.selfemployedparttime));
                })
                    .on("mouseout", function(d){ tooltip.style("display", 
"none");});

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.top) + ")")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .tickValues(x.domain().filter(function(d,i){ return !(i%4)}))
        .ticks(10))
        .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 4)
    .attr("x", 4)

    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(25)")
    .style("text-anchor", "start");


svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "centerline")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + y(0) + ")")
            .call(centerLine);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

function stackMin(serie) {
  return d3.min(serie, function(d) { return d[0]; });
}

function stackMax(serie) {
  return d3.max(serie, function(d) { return d[1]; });
}

var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')
  .data(z.domain())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend')

    legend.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 70)
            .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * 25 + 100 })
            .attr("width", 18)
            .attr("height", 18)
            .style("fill", z );

            legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", 100)
            .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * 25 + 110; })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "start")
            .text(function(d, i) { return labels[i]; });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding a `console.log(d)` line to your `mouseover` code, so you can see what `d` actually contains when you hover over it.  This should allow you to better see the available data that can be displayed.

Comment: Thank you. I solved the issue eventually with a similar solution to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173318/d3v4-stacked-barchart-tooltip