# How to get a specific item name in an array of objects in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a stacked bar chart that shows years on the X axis, total numbers on the Y axis, and the rect segments are colored by item type. A sample of my data array looks like this:

```
Item, Tonnes, Year
Wheat, 38913, 2020
Sugar, 23463, 2020
Rice, 23524, 2020
Wheat, 38913, 2019
Sugar, 23463, 2019
Rice, 23524, 2019
```

The formatted data used by D3 looks like this:

```
0: {year: 1995, Animal and Vegetable Oil: 38913, total: 3168499, Bananas: 25259, Beverages: 69583, …}
1: {year: 1996, Animal and Vegetable Oil: 44523, total: 3577090, Bananas: 30500, Beverages: 46411, …}
```

On hover, I'd like to retrieve the colored segment's item and tonnes integer so that I can pass them to a tooltip on hover. But my code seems to only retrieve the year and not the item.

The important part of my D3 code looks like this:

```
  // Set up stack method
  const stack = d3.stack().keys(tonnesKeys).order(d3.alphabetical)

  // Data, stacked
  const series = stack(formattedData);
  // Create SVG element
  const svg = d3
    .select("#mainChart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  // Add a group for each row of data
  const groups = svg
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(series)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .call(yAxis)
    .style("fill", (_, i) => colors(i))

  // Add a rect for each data value
  groups
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data((d) => d)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", (_, i) => xScale(i))
    .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d[1]))
    .attr("height", (d) => yScale(d[0]) - yScale(d[1]))
    .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
};
```

The stacked bar chart looks like this:
[image]

I would love to achieve a tooltip that shows the item and the int on hover:
[image]

Thank you for your time and helping someone who is learning D3,

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42176178/7106086) on how to access the rectangle's type - it's one approach, there are others if this isn't suitable.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a `mouseenter` event that creates or updates a tooltip object. Typically this is a `div` that is created once at the start of the visualization and updated with text and location by the `mouseenter` event.

This is example code that won't work without updates to your chart:

```
const tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "svg-tooltip")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("visibility", "hidden");

  d3.selectAll("YOUR BAR CLASS")
    .on("mouseenter", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const t = d3.pointers(event, this);
      tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
        .style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px")
        .text(this.YOURTEXTATTRIBUTE)
    .on("mouseout", function(){
      tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
    });
```